# How would you declare the types of these functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

So I'm learning about Haskell at the moment, and I came across this question:

> The type of a function `f` is supposed to be `a->[a]->a`. The
>   following definitions of `f` are incorrect because their types are all
>   different from `a->[a]->a`:
>
> ```
> i. f x xs = xs
> ii. f x xs = x+1
> iii. f x xs = x ++ xs
> iv. f x (y:ys) = y
> ```

My answers as I see it are:

```
i) f :: a -> a -> a
```

This is because x or xs can be of any value and is not a list as it does not contain the ':' operator.

```
ii) f :: Int -> a -> Int
```

This is because the + operator is used on x, meaning x is of type Int.

```
iii) f :: Eq a => a -> a -> a
```

The ++ operators are used, therefore in order to concatenate they must be of the same type..?

```
iv) f :: a -> [a] -> a
```

f returns an element from the list.

The last one is definitely wrong, because it can't be of type a -> [a] -> a. Are there any others I did wrong, and why? I'm hoping I can fully understand types and how to find out the types of functions.

Comment: You can use `:t f` to obtain the type of a function.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I mean I would like to understand how to find the type myself so I can better understand types

Comment: `Eq a` doesn't mean the types are equal. `Eq a` means "`a` is a type whose values can be checked for equality using `==`". Also, when two variables have the same name they are the same, so for example a function `a -> a -> a` takes two values of type `a` (whatever that ends up being) and returns another value of `a`. If you want to indicate that two parameters can have different types you need to use different variables.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Learning by hand is fine, but you can at least use the tools to check if the answer is correct. If they aren't, you can still think about where you went wrong. I'd recommend first trying to derive them by hand, then asking ghci if you got them right, and then trying to find out where you made mistakes.

Comment: The question you quoted is incorrect (or at least imprecise). Implementation iv would typecheck just fine if you gave it the type signature `f :: a -> [a] -> a`. That's not its *most general* type, but it is (one of) its type(s).

Comment: @DanielWagner, arguably it's correct because that's not a function but only a partial function.

Answer (score 8):

> `i) f :: a -> a -> a`
>
> `f x xs = xs`
>
> This is because x or xs can be of any value and is not a list as it does not contain the ':' operator.

True, but it also does not have to be of the same type!
So, it's actually `f :: a -> b -> b`.

> `ii) f :: Int -> a -> Int`
>
> `f x xs = x+1`
>
> This is because the + operator is used on x, meaning x is of type Int.

Correct. (Actually, in Haskell we get `Num b => b -> a -> b` which generalized the `Int` to any numeric type, but it's not that important.)

> `iii) f :: Eq a => a -> a -> a`
>
> `f x xs = x ++ xs`
>
> The ++ operators are used, therefore in order to concatenate they must be of the same type..?

True, but they must be lists. Also, `Eq` is only needed if you use `==` or something which compares values.

Here, `f :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]`.

> `iv) f :: a -> [a] -> a`
>
> `f x (y:ys) = y`
>
> f returns an element from the list.

The type of `x` does not have to be the same. We get `f :: b -> [a] -> a`.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> i. f x xs = xs
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> i) f :: a -> a -> a
> ```

Although this *can* be a type signature, you make it **too restrictive**. The function takes two parameters `x` and `xs`. Initially we can reason that `x` and `xs` can have different types, so we say that `x :: a`, and `xs :: b`. Since the function returns `xs`, the return type is `b` as well, so the type is:

```
f :: a -> b -> b
f x xs = xs
```

> ```
> ii. f x xs = x+1
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> ii) f :: Int -> a -> Int
> ```

Again you make the function **too restrictive**. Let us again assume that `x :: a` and `xs :: b` have different types. We see that we return `x + 1` (or in more canonical form `(+) x 1`. Since `(+)` has signature [**`(+) :: Num c => c -> c -> c`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) (we here use `c` since `a` is already used), and `1` has signature **`1 :: Num d => d`**, we thus see that we call `(+)` with `x` and `1`, as a result we know that `a ~ c` (`a` and `c` are the same type), and `c ~ d`, so as a result we obtain the signature:

```
f :: Num c => c -> b -> c
f x xs = x+1
```

> ```
> iii. f x xs = x ++ xs
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> iii) f :: Eq a => a -> a -> a
> ```

This is **wrong**: we here see that `f` has two parameters, `x :: a` and `xs :: b`. We see that we return `(++) x xs`. Since `(++)` has signature [**`(++) :: [c] -> [c] -> [c]`**](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(%2B%2B)), we thus know that `a ~ [c]` and `b ~ [c]`, so the type is:

```
f :: [c] -> [c] -> [c]
f x xs = x ++ xs
```

> ```
> iv. f x (y:ys) = y
> ```
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> iv) f :: a -> [a] -> a
> ```

This is again **too restrictive**. Here we see again two parameters: `x` and `(y:ys)`. We first generate a type `a` for `x :: a`, and `(y:ys) :: b`, since the pattern of the second parameter is `(y:ys)`, this is a *list constructor* with as parameters **`(:) :: c -> [c] -> [c]`**. As a result we can derive that `y :: c`, and `ys :: [c]`, furthermore the pattern `(y:ys)` has type `[c]`. Since the function returns `y`, we know that the return type is `c`, so:

```
f :: a -> [c] -> c
f x (y:ys) = y
```

> **Note**: you can let Haskell derive the type of the function itself. In GHCi you can use the **`:t`** command to query the type of an expression. For example:
>
> ```
> Prelude> f x (y:ys) = y
> Prelude> :t f
> f :: t1 -> [t] -> t
> ```

Comment: For definition `iv`, `ys :: [c]` instead of `ys :: c`, I can't edit this since it's less than 6 characters.

Comment: @M.Aroosi: correct! Thanks for spotting that. Updated :)